# How to revise CVD and CPE of Ctakes to access UMLS?

Tags: java, apache, ctakes

I am a new user for cTakes. When installation, I met with difficulties in adding UMLS username and password to Ctakes. The CPU field showed that

```
C:\Users\Administrator>cd \apache-ctakes-4.0.0
C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>bin\runctakesCVD.bat  desc\ctakes-clinical-pipeline\desc\analysis_engine\AggregatePlaintextFastUMLSProcessor.xml
C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>set CURRENT_DIR=C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0
C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>if not "" == "" goto gotHome
C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>set CTAKES_HOME=C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0
C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>if exist "C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0\bin\runctakesCVD.bat" goto okHome
C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>if exist "C:\Program iles\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe" set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin;";C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>cd C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0
C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>IF "desc\ctakes-clinical-pipeline\desc\analysis_engine\AggregatePlaintextFastUMLSProcessor.xml" == "" GOTO NoParam
C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>IF NOT "" == "" GOTO MoreThanOneParam
C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>if exist "C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0\desc\ctakes-clinical-pipeline\desc\analysis_engine\AggregatePlaintextFastUMLSProcessor.xml" (
echo CVD will load AE "C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0\desc\ctakes-clinical-pipeline\desc\analysis_engine\AggregatePlaintextFastUMLSProcessor.xml"
 java -cp "C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0\desc\;C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0\resources\;C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0\lib\*" -Dlog4j.configuration=file:\C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0\config\log4j.xml -Xms512M -Xmx3g org.apache.uima.tools.cvd.CVD -desc desc\ctakes-clinical-pipeline\desc\analysis_engine\AggregatePlaintextFastUMLSProcessor.xml
)  else (echo Unable to find descriptor "desc\ctakes-clinical-pipeline\desc\analysis_engine\AggregatePlaintextFastUMLSProcessor.xml"
 GOTO NoParam)
CVD will load AE "C:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0\desc\ctakes-clinical-pipeline\desc\analysis_engine\AggregatePlaintextFastUMLSProcessor.xml"
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [ProgressAppender] additivity to [false].
log4j: Level value for ProgressAppender is  [INFO].
log4j: ProgressAppender level set to INFO
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%m].
log4j: Adding appender named [noEolAppender] to category [ProgressAppender].
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [ProgressDone] additivity to [false].
log4j: Level value for ProgressDone is  [INFO].
log4j: ProgressDone level set to INFO
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [eolAppender] to category [ProgressDone].
log4j: Level value for root is  [INFO].
log4j: root level set to INFO
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [consoleAppender] to category [root].
14 十二月 2018 00:54:49  INFO Chunker - Chunker model file: org/apache/ctakes/chunker/models/chunker-model.zip
14 十二月 2018 00:54:50  INFO TokenizerAnnotatorPTB - Initializing org.apache.ctakes.core.ae.TokenizerAnnotatorPTB
14 十二月 2018 00:54:50  INFO ContextDependentTokenizerAnnotator - Finite state machines loaded.
14 十二月 2018 00:54:50  INFO AbstractJCasTermAnnotator - Using dictionary lookup window type: org.apache.ctakes.typesystem.type.textspan.Sentence
14 十二月 2018 00:54:50  INFO AbstractJCasTermAnnotator - Exclusion tagset loaded: CC CD DT EX IN LS MD PDT POS PP PP$ PRP PRP$ RP TO VB VBD VBG VBN VBP VBZ WDT WP WPS WRB
14 十二月 2018 00:54:50  INFO AbstractJCasTermAnnotator - Using minimum term text span: 3
14 十二月 2018 00:54:50  INFO AbstractJCasTermAnnotator - Using Dictionary Descriptor: org/apache/ctakes/dictionary/lookup/fast/sno_rx_16ab.xml
14 十二月 2018 00:54:50  INFO DictionaryDescriptorParser - Parsing dictionary specifications:
14 十二月 2018 00:54:50  INFO UmlsUserApprover - Checking UMLS Account at https://uts-ws.nlm.nih.gov/restful/isValidUMLSUser for user CHANGE_ME:
.............................. 10
............14 十二月 2018 00:55:05 ERROR UmlsUserApprover -   UMLS Account at https://uts-ws.nlm.nih.gov/restful/isValidUMLSUser is not valid for user CHANGE_ME with CHANGE_ME
```

How can I revise the two files of CVD and CPE?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @yuan you gotta provide proper username and password in UMLS related XML in cTAKES. As per the stacktrace, its trying to connect with username - CHANGE_ME which is wrong

Comment: @Gandhi I have changed all CHANGE_ME in my project yet i keep getting same error " UMLS Account at https://uts-ws.nlm.nih.gov/restful/isValidUMLSUser is not valid for user CHANGE_ME with CHANGE_ME" the only place has CHANGE_ME now is in maven dependencies repository in "C:\Users\myuser\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\ctakesresources\ctakes-resources-sno_rx\4.0.0\ctakes-resources-sno_rx-4.0.0.jar" how to fix that?

Comment: @asmgx if i remember correct, it needs to be updated in sno_rx XML file. Check this link - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CTAKES/cTAKES+4.0+User+Install+Guide were it guides to pass these params as JVM args